# Long Search Strings

Tags: support, tag-search, search-box

I am searching for [C++] questions. I do this based on tags.

Furthermore, I do want to answer [C++] and C++ related questions with tags like `vector`, `stack`, `string` or other C++ language elements.

I do not want to get results for specific topics, like "vulcan", "opengl", "yaml", "cmake" or similar.

For that reason, I use for example:

```
[c++] duplicate:no closed:no answers:0 -[qt] -[boost] -[opengl] -[opencv] -[java] -[javascript]
 -[mingw] -[yaml-cpp] -[directx] -[capnproto] -[dlopen] -[cmake] -[sfml] -[openssl]
 -[zerimq] -[unreal-engine4] -[macos]
```

I stored this as a browser bookmark.

But, unfortunately, the length for the input field is limited. And so, I cannot add more exclusions.

Is there any way to overcome this shortage? Maybe by search in search results, or a config file, or a script or similar?

Comment: is duplicate:no really necessary when you also have closed:no ? And surely you don't get THAT many search results with both c++ and java/javascript tags?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a specific feature request in the question, it just asks how to save a long search filter ..?

Comment: @Teemu. The feature request is a “longer” search string.

Comment: @Gimby The search string length is by far not sufficient. There are so many tags that I do not want to see. And there are more and more. The above is just one short example.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info

Comment: Can't you also ignore the tags you don't want to see? That way you could maybe cut out some of that length

Comment: Hm, I just noticed, that my "Feature Request" tag vanished and was replaced by "support". Just for the readers of comments that cannot follow . . .

Comment: If you really don't want to see those tags, you can put them on "ignored tags" instead and set them to "hide".

Comment: Depending on the tags you want to not be displayed, as well, you might be able use wildcards. [`[c++] -[java*]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20-java*) would omit *any* posts with a tag that starts with Java (which would include both [[tag:java]] and [[tag:javascript]], along with several other tags).

Comment: You can almost do this with [filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoQhh.png), (since there's no apparent limit to filtered tags) but there's nothing to filter closed/open questions. I posted a [feature request of my own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355243/323179) for that.

Comment: @Peter I get that the search string is limited in size and that it hurts you, but there is no way that this is going to be changed anytime soon so if you want to make any progress right now, it'll have to be a workaround. Like not filtering on tags which only produce a minimum of noise in the results.